# Angular UI-grid not changing based on the checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

My UI-grid is not reflecting changing based on the checkbox. 
Checkbox I have is --> mainCtrl.check700 (either true or false)
UI Grid does not refresh based on the checkbox change. How do i make the UI grid to change isrowselectable based on checkbox

```
mainCtrl.mainGrid.isRowSelectable = function (row) {

            if (mainCtrl.check700){
                if (row.entity.detailStatus === '700') {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                if (row.entity.detailStatus === '100' || row.entity.detailStatus === '200'  ) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it to `$scope.gridOptions`

So in your case I suppose using `mainCtrl.gridOptions.isRowSelectable = ...` instead of `mainCtrl.mainGrid.isRowSelectable` should solve the problem.